# How do I have an animation always start from the same position on screen instead of the animation playing from its current position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I'm working on a menu system but am having trouble with the animations.
I need to have it so that at the start of the animation its position starts somewhere else. So if the panel has moved to the right off the screen, when I hit the button it can come in from the left. Instead, no matter what I've done, the animation will just play from where ever it currently is and I can't move its position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Animator system, it always considers the GameObject local position.

So you could parent the animated GameObject and move it's parent around, while preserving the animation coordinates.